# Ubuntu upgrade 17.10 to 18.04 moved my MariaDB database to folder /var/lib/mysql-10.2 and downgraded MariaDB from 10.2 to 10.1

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, database, mariadb

[This is more of a How-To-Post]

Ubuntu upgrade process to 18.04 had a window asking me what I wanted to do with my MariaDB install -- install **MariaDB in Debian**, or keep my install (a working **MariaDB 10.2** install.) I must have select to do a Debian install, something that made sense to me at the time. Unfortunately this jailed (moved) my 10.2 database to a new location `/var/lib/mysql-10.2`. And downgraded my MariaDB install to a **MariaDB 10.1** in Debian in place. Unfortunately it was only after the fact that this upgrade process prompted me about the fact that I will have to do a dump/import to regain access to all my data.  Not easy to do if all I got is a copy of the database file/folder structure in `/var/lib/mysql-10.2`.

Now my Server version (after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade) is: **10.1.29-MariaDB-6 - Ubuntu 18.04**

I ended up uninstalling 10.1 and everything related to it

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server* mariadb*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
```

reinstall **MariaDB 10.2**

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server-10.2
```

stop mysql server

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

following [these direction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964417/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-mysql-database-from-the-var-lib-mysql-database-fold) I copied the missing databases from `/var/lib/mysql-10.2` back to `/var/lib/mysql`. **ONLY the missing database folder and content.** And replaced these files: `ib_buffer_pool`, `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0`, and `ib_logfile1` with the original files from `/var/lib/mysql-10.2`

reset permissions to folder and content

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

All seemed to work as planed, but somehow I was not able to gain access to the data. What made it finally work is running this as root:

```
mysqlcheck --all-databases -p
```

If you are back up and running, make sure to remove `innodb_force_recovery = 5`

I hope this helps someone stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated above ... [This is more of a How-To-Post]